# Define a function with variables linked implicitly

Tags: plotting, function-construction

I would like to define a function $f(x,y)$, with the variables x and y linked by an equation implicitly, so $f(x,y)=f(x(y),y)=f(y)$.

Eventually I would like to draw a graph with $f(x(y),y)$ being the output and $y$ being the input.

One example is $f(x,y)=x+y$ and $exp(xy)=y$. How can I do it?

Comment: try `ClearAll[f, g, h]; f[x_, y_] := x + y; g[y_] := Log[y]/y; h[y_] := f[g[y], y]`

Comment: Thanks. What if the relationship is more complicated, say y=cos(xy)+exp(x)+exp(y)? That is, I cannot rearrange the variables to define g[y_]?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34092/484

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me the question is more about calculating the function than generating the plot.

Given an equation that cannot be solved symbolically, we can approximate the implicit function with `NDSolve`.  (There are several examples on this site., e.g., [Getting an InterpolatingFunction from a ContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7944/getting-an-interpolatingfunction-from-a-contourplot), [Plotting implicitly-defined space curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/plotting-implicitly-defined-space-curves/64923#64923).)

```
implicitFunction::usage = "implicitFunction[equation, {y, y0}, {x, x0, start, end}]";
Begin["implicitFunction`"];
implicitFunction[eq_, {f_Symbol, f1_?NumericQ},
     {x_Symbol, x1_?NumericQ, xmin_?NumericQ, xmax_?NumericQ}] :=
  Block[{f0, xt},
   f0 = f /. FindRoot[eq /. x -> x1, {f, f1}];
   NDSolveValue[
     {eq /. {x -> x[xt], f -> f[xt]}, x'[xt] == 1, f[x1] == f0, x[x1] == x1},
     f, {xt, xmin, xmax}]
   ];
End[];
```

We need to propose a domain for our approximation and approximate initial values for `x` and `y`.  `FindRoot` is used to refine the initial value for the function `x`.

```
eq1 = Exp[x y] == y;
ξ = implicitFunction[eq1, {x, 0}, {y, 1, -3, 3}];
```

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At `` implicitFunction`xt == 1.111713753522611`*^-16 ``, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

The warning just means that `NDSolve` has computed the domain for us:

```
ξ["Domain"]
(*  {{1.11171*10^-16, 3.}}  *)

Plot[ξ[y] + y, Evaluate @ Flatten[{y, ξ["Domain"]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One could further process the result by wrapping the interpolating function with `FindRoot`.  For this we need to add the attribute `HoldAll`.  The following could be incorporated as a second definition of `implicitFunction`, but here I'll simply make a second definition.  The only advantage is when a more accurate value is needed.  One can take advantage of the `FindRoot` options.

```
SetAttributes[implicitFunction2, HoldAll];
implicitFunction2[eq_, f_Symbol, x_Symbol, init_: (0 &), opts : OptionsPattern[FindRoot]][x1_?NumericQ] := 
  Block @@ Hold[{f, x}, f /. FindRoot[eq /. x -> x1, {f, init[x1]}]];
```

The `init` function supplies the initial value for the root.  We can use the `NDSolve` interpolating function to do that (at least within its domain).

```
ξ2 = implicitFunction2[eq1, x, y, ξ];
Plot[ξ2[y] + y, Evaluate@Flatten[{y, ξ["Domain"]}]]
(* plot looks the same as above *)
```

This form also works with the default `init`, but that is because the equation is easy to solve from any starting point.

```
ξ2 = implicitFunction2[eq1, x, y];
```

Of course, it's slower than just using `ξ`.

Answer (score 4):

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y
g[x_, y_] := Exp[x y] - y;
ParametricPlot[{y, f[x, y]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{a, b, x, y}, g[x, y]]}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 MeshStyle -> {{Opacity[1], Thick, Black}}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What does MeshFunctions -> {Function[{a, b, x, y} stand for? To follow up my question, how can I define the function f(x(y),y)? I would like to use the function to do more.

Comment: @Rahul +1 very nice trick.

Comment: @fanshenry: Sorry, I took "Eventually I would like to draw a graph" to mean that drawing the graph was your end goal. To define the function itself, you can try using `Solve` or `NSolve` or use Michael E2's method. When I have some more time, I'll edit my answer to explain the use of `MeshFunctions`, but in the meantime you could look at the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html).

Answer (score 4):

My preferred method would be using @rahul's `Mesh` trick. 
You can also use the option `Exclusions` as follows:

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y
g[x_, y_] := Exp[x y] - y;
ParametricPlot[{y, f[x, y]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 Frame -> False, PlotRange -> All, BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> None,
 Exclusions -> {g[x, y] == 0}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], EdgeForm[Blue], Blue, Antialiasing -> True]]
```

[image]

Note: Unlike @rahul's method which produces a single `Line` primitive, this method produces `Polygon`s.

Answer (score 1):

If post processing is acceptable then:

```
ContourPlot[Exp[x y] == y, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Frame -> False, 
  Axes -> True] /. 
 GraphicsComplex[a_, b___] :> 
  GraphicsComplex[({#2, #2 + #1} &) @@@ a, b]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also eliminate the implicit dependency by using `Solve`, e.g.:

```
res=Solve[Exp[x y]==y,x][[1,1]]/.C[1]->0
```

and apply the result to the output function:

```
x+y/.res
```

or combine the steps into one:

```
x+y/.Solve[Exp[x y]==y,x][[1,1]]/.C[1]->0
(* y+Log[y]/y *)
```

This way, you end with the desired function of `y` only, may use standard plotting, and of course any other analytics, differentiate, …

```
Plot[Evaluate[x+y/.Solve[Exp[x y]==y,x][[1,1]]/.C[1]->0],{y,-5,5}]
```

[image: y+Log[y]/y]